# Import Error: Getting an error to import 'Factor' from 'pgmpy.factors' ,what should I do now?

Tags: python, markov-models, pgmpy

I am getting error when I am import 'Factor' from 'pgmpy.factors'
what should I do now

I am try to install Factor using pip but that does not work that's give me an error
and as I very new to probabilistic graphical model(pgmpy) so please do help and please tell that where I do mistake

Thank You,

Comment: Hello. Please add full error message to your question so we can help you.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)